# How to send formData object as key value pair in Vue js?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, javascript-objects, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload an image with vue and laravel on backend. Everything was going well until I ran into a problem. My image gets sent when i make an axios call sending formData only as an argument.

```
 let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append("image", this.image);
 axios.post('url',formData)
```

But on axios request I want to send an object, not just the formData, something like this:

```
const myObj={ name:'hello','shop_id':2, image:formData }
axios.post('url',myObj)
```

But this doesn't work. Is there any way I can work around with this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `name` and `shop_id` values to the `FormData` object. In this case `FormData` is the container in which you can send all of your data.

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', this.image);
formData.append('name', 'hello');
formData.append('shop_id', 2);
axios.post('url',formData)
```

If your data becomes more complex and you need to send a big object with loads of data, then you could send the the object as a JSON value in one of the keys.

```
const complexObject = {
  ...loads of data here
};

formData.append('complexObject', JSON.stringify(complexObject))
```

Parse the JSON back to usable code on the server side to use the data inside the complex object.

Comment: Thank you. I feel so stupid I didn't think about this. You are a life saver :)

Comment: I've added an example how to just do that.